# MS Access to Plain Text using VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a 'accdb' file and it has some queries.

Now I want use the query's output to be redirected to a text file and each of the fields are delimited by tabs.

I might have to do this multiple times over the course of the month, so I would like a button and on-clicking it it takes the queries 1 by 1 and create a new file for every query. How can I do this?

BTW the 1st row would be the field names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code, first you have to create specification like [here](http://www.blueclaw-db.com/export-specifications.htm) and replace name YourName with it's name and Query1 with your query name:

```
DoCmd.TransferText TransferType:=acExportFixed, _
SpecificationName:="YourName", _
TableNAme:="Query1", _
FileName:="d:\test.txt", _
HasFieldNames:=-1
```

Comment: This worked fine. Is there a way I could customize the column names?

Comment: You may change the names in query, or make other query just for export and rename the fileds there. That's the easiest way.

Comment: I get a runtime error everytime saying "...could not find object test.txt'..." Any ideas on how to solve this, I need to create this file everytime

Comment: The Microsoft Access database engine could not find the object <name>. Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly. (Error 3011) - this is the error

Comment: I've checked that code, maybe you don't have letter D: drive or you dont have permissions, as I remember windows don't allow to write do disc C: directly. Remember to change names both of your specification and query.

Comment: I have checked all those parameters, I also tried to create an empty file and try, but no use :(

Comment: I am logged in as Administrator and also I tried it with 'D' drive too, I get the same errors, I have checked the permissions and all the other related stuff too.

Comment: Not sure what the problem was, I did it from the beginning and now at-least I don't get the error, no data is getting written, and every-time I run it a empty view is created. Any solution for this problem?

Comment: Is D: your CD/DVD drive? The problem here is that you just need to find the right path/filename. There's nothing actually wrong with the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the TransferText method to export it as type acLinkDelim. You can write this into a bit of code behind the click event of a button or put it into a public function that takes a query name and an output path and does the rest for you

Comment: To change the column name output, just build a query and export that. You can go:

Select fn as FirstName, LN as LastName from tblCustomers order by LN

The above query would thus rename your columns. You can also do  this in the query builder if you not confortable typing in sql in sql view mode. So, in the query builder to do the above, just type in for the column name 

FirstName:FN

So, the above will result in renamed columns in the Now use the name of the query in place of the table. As the above shows, this will also allow you to set the order etc.